# Всплывающее меню

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на `menu-button` впервые, исполнялся код №1, а при втором и последующих нажатиях - код №2?

```
// № 1    —    подгружает меню

// когда пользователь кликнул по кнопке menu-button (показать меню), запрашиваем меню GET-запросом
$(".menu-button").click(function(e)
{
    $.get("index", "menu", serverResponse, "json");
    e.preventDefault();
});

function serverResponse(data)
{
    // если есть ошибки при выполнении запроса, выводим ошибки
    if (data.notice)
    {
        $(".notice-box").html(data.notice).show();
    }
    else
    {   
        $("#title, #content").slideUp(100);     // прячем контент, который был на странице до вызова меню
        $("#menu").html(data.menu).slideDown(600);  // показываем меню, которое запросили с помощью `menu-button`
    }
}

// № 2    —    этот код показывает либо контент либо меню с плавным переходом, меню при этом уже должно быть загружено (получено браузером) ранее

$(".menu-button")
    .blur(function()
    {
        $("#menu").slideUp(600);
        $("#title, #content").slideDown(100);
    })
    .click(function()
    {
        $("#menu").finish();
        if ($("#menu").is(":hidden"))
        {
            $("#title, #content").slideUp(100);
        }
        else
        {
            $("#title, #content").slideDown(100);
        }
        $("#menu").slideToggle(600); 
    });
```

`#title` и `#content`   — это контент
`#menu`                     — это меню

В результате должно получиться так:
На странице, при ее загрузке, имеется контент.
При первом вызове меню (нажатие пользователем `menu-button`), меню подгружается запросом `/index.php?menu`
после подгрузки меню, контент прячется, а меню при этом показывается.
При последующих вызовах меню (нажатие пользователем `menu-button`) должно выполняться все, что выше, только без подгрузки данных через GET-запрос `/index.php?menu`,
то есть выводится либо контент либо меню с плавным переходом.

Comment: Пара глупых идей: `1)` добавить счетчик. И при нажатии смотреть, если нажали 1 раз, то грузить контент, если он больше 1, не грузить...... `2)` Результат `get` запроса должен положить в переменную. И Если она есть, не Null - то не грузить аякс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно при вызове проверять на .is('.opened');
при первом вызове добавлять класс "opened", а при последующих - проверять на его(класса) наличие

```
$('.menu-button').click(function(e){
    if($(this).is('.opened')) {
        //Выполняем код №2
    } else {
        //Выполняем код №1
        $(this).addClass('opened');
    }
});
```

Comment: Это тот случай когда можно проверить есть ли на странице ID `#menu`. Можно как-то проверить присутствие на странице `div id="menu"`?

Comment: $('div').is('#menu')

Comment: `if($('div').is('#menu')) { //Выполняем код №2 } else  { //Выполняем код №1 }` — это будет аналогично вашему примеру?

Comment: Да, вполне: `$('div')` - возвращает коллекцию div'ов, из которой `.is('#menu')` возвращает true или false по наличию или отсутствию div'a с указанным id соответственно.

Comment: Скажите еще, в обратную сторону так проверять: `if ($("div").is("#menu") == false)` ? (чтобы поменять код №2 и №1 местами)

Comment: обратную проверку можно получить добавив `!` к исходному выражению - логическое отрицание. `if (!$("div").is("#menu"))`

Answer (score 2):

запишите в какую нибудь переменную ответ и проверяйте его на undefined вместо запроса, что-то вроде

```
if (typeof receivedData !== 'undefined') {
  serverResponse(data)
} else {
 $.get("index", "menu", serverResponse, "json");
}
```

если меню разное, то можно так:

```
if (typeof $(this).data('receivedData') !== 'undefined') {
  serverResponse(data)
} else {
 $.get("index", "menu", serverResponse, "json");
}
```

потом, там где меню показываем делаем

```
$(menuButton).data('receivedData', data);
```

но у вас меню одно, так что хватит переменной в вышестоящей области видимости.